# How to compile nginx form source on windows?

Tags: gcc, nginx, mingw, clang, visual-studio-2015

I have tried several days to compile nginx from source in Windows.

I am under Windows 10, with msys, mingw, VS2015 and clang at hand.

I have several tries, and none of them works:

1. I've downloaded the version from github master branch.
   here is the configure:

auto/configure --with-cc=gcc --prefix="c:\nginx" --without-http_rewrite_module --without-http_gzip_module

It compiles successfully and runs, but when accessing the very basic index.html from browser, I have been kept getting:

2015/08/13 20:31:46 [alert] 25500#25508: *2 WSARecv() failed (10055: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full) while reading client request line, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "���'

in the error log. And the connection always resets,

2. I tried to compile it with clang, But clang won't understand some of the definitions.
   here is the configure:

auto/configure --with-cc=clang --prefix="c:\nginx" --without-http_rewrite_module --without-http_gzip_module

3. I've downloaded the 1.9.2 version source from http://wiki.nginx.org/Install and with mingw
   here is the configure:

./configure --with-cc=gcc --prefix="c:\nginx" --without-http_rewrite_module --without-http_gzip_module
and the make process failed for "no rule to make target 'src/os/win32/nginx_win32_config.h'

4.I've downloaded source form http://hg.nginx.org/nginx
here is the configure:
auto/configure --with-cc=gcc --prefix="c:\nginx" --without-http_rewrite_module --without-http_gzip_module

and the make process failed for "no rule to make target 'objs/src/core/ngx_file.o'

5.for 1.9.2 and source from hg, clang fails the same as #2.

I need to build nginx on windows with a custom module, any idea how I can build a workable nginx from source?

Comment: I've built nginx taken at https://github.com/nginx/nginx/archive/release-1.11.4.tar.gz with Visual Studio 2013 for 32-bit Windows, using busybox taken from https://github.com/rmyorston/busybox-w32 to run configure scripts. Used pre-buillt static zlib, pcre, openssl

Comment: I will try it thanks

Answer (score 0):

append `--with-select_module` to configure